# On Android how to call from TextView inside a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, textview

I am trying to call when someone tap or click on a number which in a TextView.

I have added permission in Android AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Also I have set the TextView `android:clickable="true"`

I am very new in Android development so please Help me.

I am sorry for my bad English.

Here is My code **AboutDeveloper.java**

```
package com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AboutDeveloper extends Fragment {

    public AboutDeveloper(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final TextView tv_phone = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.devMobile);
        tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String phone_no= tv_phone.getText().toString().replaceAll(":", "");
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_developer, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
09-20 20:28:05.852      622-622/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.AboutDeveloper.onCreateView(AboutDeveloper.java:22)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code by this code and tell me what is the output.

```
public class AboutDeveloper extends Fragment {

public AboutDeveloper(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_developer, container, false);

    final TextView tv_phone = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.devMobile);
    tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                String uri = "tel:"+tv_phone.getText().toString();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your call has failed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        });

    return v;
}
```

Since you were getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.AboutDeveloper.onCreateView(AboutDeveloper.java:22)
```

it meant that it was not able to find the view element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am checking now

Comment: Your Code Works :)  "but a little correction needed you missed '}' for closing public void onClick... Its works like a magic :)

Comment: sorry, please accept the answer if it has helped you, if possible kindly upvote it, il edit the answer :-)

Comment: What should I need to do if I want to move the number to dial instead of direct calling.

Comment: Just use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead of Intent.ACTION_CALL

Comment: NP, kindly upvote the answer, since i answered additional question :-)

Comment: Online tutorials, the new boston and StackOverflow

Comment: its ok NP, all the best :-)

Comment: How to promote save the number to phonebook instead of call & dial when someone tap the textview?

Comment: After setOnClickListener has finished work, call a function, in that function put this code as given http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html